# Send CROSS DOMAIN base64 string using AJAX

Tags: jquery, base64, shopify

I am getting error while sending base64 in ajax request using GET method. I can only use get method as shopify does not allow cross domain with any other method.

**GET https://example.com/abc/uploadfile.php?callback=undefined&image=%5B%22data%3Aim**

net::ERR_ABORTED 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        image: JSON.stringify(dataUrl.match(/.{1,3000}/g))
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "example.com/uploadfile.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is the CODE

              $.ajax({
                type:     "GET",
                data: {image:JSON.stringify(dataUrl.match(/.{1,3000}/g))},
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url:      "https://example.com/uploadfile.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("success");
                } 
              });

Comment: To add details to your question, use the "edit" link under the question (above the comments) rather than posting a comment. (I've done it for you.)

Comment: Unless other domain allows it you can't perform directly cross-domain reauests using ajax, only opaque requests using fetch() alternatively you can pass everything thorugh backend - backend can contact other domains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cross domain request with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627892/cross-domain-request-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use of [App Proxy](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/application-proxies)

With the app proxy you can send request to same domain, regardless weather it is post or get.

Shopify will automatically redirect your request to your application End Point.

Answer (score 0):

If it's true that:

1. You have to do this cross-domain; and
2. Shopify only allows cross-domain ajax requests with GET (not POST); and
3. Your data is so long that the URI containing is is too long for your browser, their server, or some intermediary;

then your only option is not to do that. Instead, you might pass the data through a server under your control that will then send it on to Shopify using POST (since the Same Origin Policy is a browser thing).

Comment: thank you for your answer but how I can achieve that can you guide me please

Comment: @AmanKalra - That's far too broad a question for SO's Q&A format. You'll need to decide on what kind of server to host (you had PHP in the question at one point, so perhaps PHP?), then look at how to receive files with that technology, how to do HTTP requests to other sites using that technology, etc.